# How do I show the Date Changed column in Windows 10 Explorer?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-explorer, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to preface this to say I am **not** asking how to show the Date Modified column. [Date Changed is different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65099502/61624), as described in that link.

Here's an example of the difference: if you move a file to another directory, the Date Changed becomes the current date whereas Date Modified stays the same. If I could see and sort by the Date Changed column, it would be a good indication of when a file was moved into that folder.

This field can be accessed in powershell, wsl, etc. For example, notice the `Change:` row in this output:

```
C:\Users\erhannis\Downloads\nsx220en>stat nsx-2.2.0
  File: nsx-2.2.0
  Size: 0               Blocks: 4          IO Block: 65536  directory
Device: c6194f59h/3323547481d   Inode: 7318349397564576  Links: 1
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (1056947/   erhannis)   Gid: (1049089/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2016-03-24 14:41:17.880026600 -0400
Modify: 2016-03-24 14:41:17.880026600 -0400
Change: 2020-12-01 17:03:41.697541400 -0500
 Birth: 2016-03-24 14:35:09.540397700 -0400
```

I want to know if there is a way to include this as one of the columns in Windows Explorer so I can sort a directory by it.

Comment: I believe that this is the [MFT Entry Modified](https://github.com/files-community/Files/issues/3244) attribute and the explorer doesn't expose this.

Comment: Explorer is not modifiable, so no way. A third-party file manager might perhaps do it. Or you could use PowerShell to generate a CSV list of files and sort using Excel for example.

Comment: Can you get it from PowerShell?